# Nativescript - how to get local-storage not to clear during sessions

Tags: nativescript

With {N} 2.5, every time I do the following command, it inits app storage (application-settings module). So I can't test different app states. Same for tns build android.

`tns livesync android --emulator --watch`

This wasn't the case with pre 2.5 - the build command DID init but the livesync command didn't.

Any other way?

I'd like to save a few app states and then restart the app and have application-settings previously saved to be present.

Comment: Just use `tns run android` and the app settings should persist during development. This command defaults to live syncing in 2.5

Comment: It doesn't seem to - at least on android w/ NS 2.5.

Comment: Works for me. Might have some issue in your code that is being executed or a version mismatch in your NS setup/config.

Comment: are you in 2.5 or 2.5.1. also i'm retrieving a string from application-settings in the app-launch event. could that be the problem?

Comment: a `tns build` will rebuild your application, remove it  from the device, and install it again. This will inadvertently remove your app settings. If you develop using `tns run android` (which is the equivalent of the now to-be-deprecated `tns livesync --watch`) only script/xml/css file changes will be transferred to device, and the app restarted, but not removed.

Comment: It's getting re-initialized if i do `tns run android` again from the command line. That is, I stop the emulator and reissue the command from the CLI. All the settings are gone.